# Alphauser Points Error An error has occurred. 0 Using $this when not in object context

Tags: joomla

Everything was working well on my site yesterday. I upgraded my php version to from 5.6 to 7.0.9

Then I received the following error: An error has occurred.
 0 Using $this when not in object context

I am relatively clueless on how to correct this, otherwise AUP is useless. Does anyone have some direction - as I am not sure what file may need to be modified, and what that modification could be?

I am not 100% sure upgrading to 7.0.9 was what caused it. I just believe it had something to do with it.

Thank you

Comment: I too faced the same issue when i upgraded to 7.0.9. I need to have proper look into the changelogs of php 7.0.9. it works well with the lower versions.

Comment: Agreed. I did find the issue in question after debugging the platform. It was in an admin helper file. I consulted with the new owners of Aplhauser Points only to become discouraged as they don't seem to know or care enough to help a paying customer. Very disappointed to say the least.